# Запуск скриптов Chrome extension только в активной вкладке

Tags: google-chrome, extension

Подскажите, у кого есть опыт в разработке расширений под Chrome, можно ли ограничить запуск контентных скриптов только текущей активной вкладкой?

Т.е. задача в общих чертах такова, при запуске расширения открылась новая вкладка и на ней есть много разных ссылок. При переходе по ссылкам (ссылки открываются в этой же вкладке), пользователю показывается меню расширения. 
Вопрос в том, как это реализовать именно в рамках текущей активной вкладки. 
Пробовал всем ссылкам добавлять параметр `myparam=1` и в manifest.json прописать правило `*://*/*myparam*`, но если например при переходе по ссылке происходит редирект, то параметр теряется. Поэтому есть идея разрешить все урлы, но ограничить все одной вкладкой.

Comment: А что открывает эту вкладку ? Для этого у вас же должен быть какой нибудь бакграунд скрипт или какой то еще более глобальный, чем контент. Вот он при открытии вкладки пусть и сообщает бакграунду (если это не сам бакграунд) А бакграунд запоминает у себя id вкладки. контент скрипт пусть стартует всегда но в самом начале обращается к бакраунду и тот будет ему сообщать в той ли он запустился вкладке и надо ли тут работать

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, за отличный совет. Получилось реализовать, сравнивая в background.js в chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener id отрытой вкладки и текущей активной и если они одинаковые то посылаем сообщение в content.js